# Scala not infered type

Tags: scala, slick

I have a method with this signature:

```
def fn1[A1, P, Q, E, U, C[_]](
  fn: A1 => Query[E, U, C],
  sorts: (E => Rep[_], String)*
)(implicit
  aShape: Shape[ColumnsShapeLevel, A1, P, A1],
  pShape: Shape[ColumnsShapeLevel, P, P, _]
) = ???
```

and in my class I have a slick query defined as:

```
protected def base(id: Rep[Long]): Query[(entity1Table, entity2Table), (Entity1, Entity2), Seq] = ???
```

Now, I want to do something like this:

```
fn1(base, (_._1.name, "name"))
```

or, at least

```
fn1(base, (x => x._1.name, "name"))
```

but even with the second way, scala cannot infer the type of x, that is `(entity1Table, entity2Table)`, so to make it compile correctly I have to explicitly tell the type of x writing this

```
fn1(base, ((x: (entity1Table, entity2Table)) => x._1.name, "name"))
```

Why scala cannot infer the type and what can I do to make scala infer the type automatically?

Comment: try currying `fn1`, i.e. define it as `fn1(fn)(sorts)` to see if it helps

Comment: thank you, but sadly it doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

This is because the type parameters of your `sorts` are derived from the  `first` parameter `fn`. But if you pass both of them at the same time, the compiler does not know anything about `fn` yet and hence fails to derive for `sorts`.

You need to `curry` your `fn1` so that the compiler can first work on `fn` and then use the derived types to make sense of `sorts`.

I am a bit confused by the use your terms `entity1Table` etc... so I drew up a mock schema to go with the example.

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver

import H2Driver.api._

case class Entity1(i: Int, s: String)
case class Entity2(i: Int, s: String)

class Entity1T(tag: Tag) extends Table[Entity1](tag, "Entity1s") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey) // This is the primary key column
  def name = column[String]("name")

  def * = (id, name) <> (Entity1.tupled, Entity1.unapply)
}

val entity1Table = TableQuery[Entity1T]

class Entity2T(tag: Tag) extends Table[Entity2](tag, "Entity2s") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey) // This is the primary key column
  def name = column[String]("name")

  def * = (id, name) <> (Entity2.tupled, Entity2.unapply)
}

val entity2Table = TableQuery[Entity2T]
```

Now, I am not sure which one do you want, this one

```
def fn1[A1, P, Q, E, U, C[_]](
  fn: A1 => Query[E, U, C]
)(
  sort: (U => Rep[_], String)*
)(implicit
  aShape: Shape[ColumnsShapeLevel, A1, P, A1],
  pShape: Shape[ColumnsShapeLevel, P, P, _]
) = ???

protected def base1(id: Rep[Long]): Query[(TableQuery[Entity1T], TableQuery[Entity2T]), (Entity1T, Entity2T), Seq] = ???

val x1 = fn1(base1)((etq => etq._1.name, "name"))
```

Or this one,

```
def fn2[A1, P, Q, E, U, C[_]](
  fn: A1 => Query[E, U, C]
)(
  sort: (E => Rep[_], String)*
)(implicit
  aShape: Shape[ColumnsShapeLevel, A1, P, A1],
  pShape: Shape[ColumnsShapeLevel, P, P, _]
) = ???

protected def base2(id: Rep[Long]): Query[(Entity1T, Entity2T), (Entity1, Entity2), Seq] = ???

val x2 = fn1(base1)((etq => etq._1.name, "name"))
```

From what I can see, both of the versions are able to derive types.

Comment: You have right... I've used this `{}` braces so I get compilation error but in this way `fn1(base1)((etq => etq._1.name, "name"))` it works correctly.

Sorry for the misleading question...

Now what can I do? Is better to mark your answer as the correct one o I have to delete my question?

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is because functions are contravariant: `_._1.name` could be `(entity1Table, entity2Table) => String` or it could be `Any => String`, and either would satisfy the type constraint, because the latter is a subclass of the former.